# Python:dict comprehension and eval function variable scope

Tags: python-3.x, scope, global-variables, dictionary-comprehension

Code 1: for loop

```py
def foo():
    one = '1'
    two = '2'
    three = '3'
    d = {}
    for name in ('one', 'two', 'three'):
        d[name] = eval(name)
    print(d)

foo()
```

output:

> {'one': '1', 'two': '2', 'three': '3'}

Code 2: dict comprehension

```py
def foo():
    one = '1'
    two = '2'
    three = '3'
    print({name: eval(name) for name in ('one', 'two', 'three')})

foo()
```

output:

> NameError: name 'one' is not defined

Code 3: add global keyword

```py
def foo():
    global one, two, three  # why?
    one = '1'
    two = '2'
    three = '3'
    print({name: eval(name) for name in ('one', 'two', 'three')})

foo()
```

output:

> {'one': '1', 'two': '2', 'three': '3'}

Dict comprehensions and generator comprehensions create their own local scope. According to the definition of the closure (or not the closure here), but why can't Code 2 access the variable `one[,two,three]` of the outer function `foo`? However, Code 3 can successfully create a dictionary by setting the variable `one[,two,three]` to global?

So is it because the `eval` function and the dict comprehensions have different scopes?

Hope someone help me, I will be grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand whats happening, try this:

```
def foo():
    global one
    one = '1'
    two = '2'
    print({'locals, global': (locals(), globals()) for _ in range(1)})

foo()
```

Output

```
{'locals, global': ({'_': 0, '.0': <range_iterator object at ...>},
                    {'__name__': '__main__', '__package__': None, ..., 'one': '1'})}
```

The builtin [`eval(expression)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) is a shortcut for `eval(expression[, globals[, locals]])`.

As you see in the previous output, `locals()` is not local symbol table of the function because list/dict comprehensions have their own scope (see https://bugs.python.org/msg348274 for instance).

To get the output you expected, you just have to pass the local symbol table of the function to `eval`.

```
def bar():
    one = '1'
    two = '2'
    three = '3'
    func_locals = locals() # bind the locals() here
    print({name: eval(name, globals(), func_locals) for name in ('one', 'two', 'three')})

bar()
```

Output

```
{'one': '1', 'two': '2', 'three': '3'}
```